# Why is my value passed through NSNotifcationCenter not preserved?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnotifications

I'm trying to send a CGPoint through an NSNotification like this

```
-(void)setPosition:(CGPoint)point
{ 
 NSString *pointString = NSStringFromCGPoint(point);

 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] 
                         initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"p", pointString, nil];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     postNotificationName:@"BownceSpriteDidSetPosition" 
     object:self 
     userInfo:dict];

 [super setPosition:CGPointMake(point.x, point.y)];
}
```

And I've implemented the observer like this

```
-(void) init
{
    if((self = [self init])){
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
       addObserver:self selector:@selector(setViewPointCenter:)           
       name:@"BownceSpriteDidSetPosition" 
       object:nil];

       // I wondered wether 'object' should be something else???

       // more code etc....
    }
    return self
}

-(void) setViewPointCenter:(NSNotification *)notification 
{

 NSString * val = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"p"];
 CGPoint point = CGPointFromString(val);

    // trying to debug
    NSString debugString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"YPOS -----> %f", point.y];
 NSLog(debugString);

 CGPoint centerPoint = ccp(240, 160);
 viewPoint = ccpSub(centerPoint, point);

 self.position = viewPoint;
}
```

But it seems that CGPoint is empty, or (0,0) maybe. Either way, it's not having the desired effect, and the debugString is showing point.y to be 0.0.

From all the examples I've found, it looks to me like I'm doing it all right. But obviously I'm not. Can anyone nudge me in the right direction and point out my mistake?

Comment: Might want to edit the title to indicate you're talking about notifications. May I suggest "Value passed through NSNotifcationCenter is not preserved"?

Comment: Without seeing what "point" is set to, it's difficult to say whether or not there's anything wrong with the code you've posted so far. What does it show up as if you log it out at the top of setPosition?

Comment: I've tried that, and point is being set perfectly. I'm actually subclassing a Cocos2d Sprite and overriding the setPosition method.

Comment: You should consider using +[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point] instead of  NSStringFromCGPoint/CGPointFromString

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your objects and keys reversed in the dictionary. It should read

```
 NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] 
                         initWithObjectsAndKeys:pointString,@"p", nil];
```

Yes, it's exactly backwards of the way you would expect it to be and this bites me about every third time I create a dictionary.

Comment: I fear this may not be the last time it bites me either. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is here:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"p", pointString, nil];
```

It should be:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:pointString, @"p", nil];
```

"Objects" comes before "Keys" in the selector, so you list your items as ObjectA, KeyForObjectA, ObjectB, KeyForObjectB, etc.

You're also leaking this dictionary, since you alloc/init it, but never release it (I'm assuming you're not using garbage collection).

Comment: memory, that's another thing I'm struggling with. Since I'm subclassing here, i'm guessing I can just override the dealloc method and release this manually?

Comment: since you're using `dict` immediately with `NSNotificationCenter`, you're safe to `[dict release]` immediately after posting the notification.  That will fix your leak.  =)

Comment: Since it's only used inside that method, just use `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:pointString, @"p", nil]` and be done with it. You can even pass it straight as the `userInfo:` parameter without storing it to a variable. Simpler, less code, no leaks. That's what autorelease pools are for.

Answer (score 0):

In new objective-c syntax is better to use:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"p": [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point]};
```

it easier to understend and it use `NSValue` instead of `NSString`.

There is also a problem with removing observer. In your code, you only use `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(setViewPointCenter:) name:@"BownceSpriteDidSetPosition" object:nil];` but never call `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];`, whitch can produce nasty crash, that would be hard to debug. I sugest you using library https://github.com/AllinMobile/AIMObservers that prevents this kind of crash. You could rewrite your code in that way:

```
__weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
self.observer = [AIMNotificationObserver observeName:@"BownceSpriteDidSetPosition" onChange:^(NSNotification *notification) {
   NSValue *valueOfPoint =  [notification userInfo][@"p"];
   CGPoint point = [valueOfPoint CGPointValue];
   CGPoint centerPoint = ccp(240, 160);
   viewPoint = ccpSub(centerPoint, point);
   //use weakSelf to avoid strong reference cycles
   weakSelf.position = viewPoint;
}];
```